# Spring @PropertySource being loaded from wrong @Configuration file

Tags: java, spring

I have two configuration files. One for builds (AppConfig) and one for testing (TestAppConfig).

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import(HttpConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = { "file:app.properties" })
public class AppConfig {
```

TestAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import(HttpConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = { "classpath:test_app.properties" })
public class TestAppConfig {

  public static final String DB_NAME = "testdb";

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .addScript("import_test.sql").setName(DB_NAME).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setPersistenceUnitName(DB_NAME);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("domain");
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaAdapter());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);

    return adapter;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator() {
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
  }

}
```

HttpConfig for completeness:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpConfig {
```

When running my test annotated as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestAppConfig.class)
public class MyTest {
```

I get an error:

```
Failed to load bean class: TestAppConfig; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: app.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Why is it trying to pull app.properties? I've specified that it use test_app.properties.

If I do a build it runs correctly with the right properties.

Comment: Does `HttpConfig` pull anything?

Comment: No it's just annotated with `@Configuration` and declares one bean.

Comment: You must something in your `TestAppConfig` that is trying to open a file. I suggest you post more of the context. Or try cleaning and re-building.

Comment: I've added the complete TestAppConfig, but I don't think there is any value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the details we have, I think the issue might be here

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package")
```

in your `TestAppConfig` class.

If your `AppConfig` class is somewhere inside that package, doing a component scan will create a bean for it (because of `@Configuration`), trying to load your properties file, which it cannot find. Be more specific/exclusive with your `@ComponentScan` packages.

Comment: LOL, some people might not know.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is probably the answer. I'll rework my package structure a bit.